# Program form input(with regex) to accept only values within a decimal range (0.0-100) with single precision with cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, firefox

I'm trying to filter an input to prevent anyone from entering numbers other than in the range of  0.0-100. Please see the code below. The issue is that it works perfectly in IE,Chrome and Opera but fails in Firefox with the regular expression. In Firefox, I cannot enter '.' (decimal dot)into the input text field.Any idea what could be wrong?

```
$('input').on('input', function() {//sanitize values entered 
match = (/(^100$|\d{1,2})[^\.]*((?:\.\d{0,1})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
console.log(match);
if(match !== null){
       this.value = match[1] + match[2];
}else this.value ="";});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe avoiding the point of the question, but is it necessary to use regex in this scenario?  You could use `parseFloat` and then ensure it's between 0 and 100, and then check the decimal places.

Comment: I agree with @Matthew that using regex is definitely not the easiest way to solve the problem, but anyways here are a few thoughts. 1) I can't reproduce the issue with Firefox, which version are you using? For me it behaves similarly to other browsers. 2) You don't need to escape the dot when it's inside square brackets. 3) 2) I can't see the purpose of the `[^\.]*` in the middle, in particular it allows any number of digits, which you do not want. 4) Your `^` and `$` only apply to '100' and therefore you could include anything (including digits) on the left and right sides of any match.

Comment: One possibilty is that Firefox is set to some European setting (in Europe, we use comma as decimal separator).

Comment: Thanks for all input guys. Actually it looks like some issue with my Firefox 62.0.2 (Quantum). Maybe its not version specific but a system issue or probably some plugin is causing the problem. I agree the escape codes have become a mess. I thought it was some issue in the expression and tried adding it up making it worse. Thanks for all your help